# Why isn't tilde (~) expanding inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, double-quotes, tilde-expansion

I want to check whether or not the hidden `.git` folder exists. First thought was to use:

```
if [ -d "~/.git" ]; then
   echo "Do stuff"
fi
```

But the `-d` apparently does not look for hidden folders.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem has to do with the tilde being within double quotes.

To get it expanded, you need to put the tilde outside the quotes:

```
if [ -d ~/".git" ]; then   # note tilde outside double quotes!
   echo "Do stuff"
fi
```

Or, alternatively, as commented below by hek2mgl, use `$HOME` instead of `~`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.git" ]
```

From POSIX in [Tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01):

> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted <tilde> character at the beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the first unquoted <slash> in the word, or all the characters in the word if there is no <slash>.

From POSIX in [Double Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_03):

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters dollar sign, backquote, and backslash, as follows:

You can find further explanations in [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/40596) from the Unix & Linux Stack.