# What would cause bash to interpret ~ as a directory literally named "~"?

Tags: bash, unix, directory, sh, digital-ocean

### Background

I'm using the Digital Ocean API to create a new server (droplet) and including a bash script to be automatically run when the server starts up the first time.

### Problem

In my bash script (which runs as root), I try to install Oh-My-Zsh via its [shell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh), which tries to install it in `~`.  However, when I ssh into the machine, I find that Oh-My-Zsh has been installed into `/~/` instead of `/root`.

### Question

**What could be causing bash to interpret `~` as the name of a folder instead of as an alias for `$HOME`, and is there anything I can do to fix this?**  The Oh My Zsh install script is not owned by me, so I can't simply change each `~` to `$HOME` or `/root` (of course I could hack together a sed command to do the replacement for me in that install script, but it seems like there should be an easier way...)

Comment: Show us the context. If the `~` is literal in a variable that's expanded, that would do it, but we'd need to see a specific instance of code that causes that error to speak authoritatively, *included as part of the question*.

Comment: Also, whether `HOME` is defined matters. (And, err, you say you're running a oh-my-zsh install script with *bash*, not zsh? There are very different, and not mutually-compatible, shells)

Comment: ...example: `var="~/foo"; mkdir -p "$var"` will cause the problem, but that's just one of many possible mechanisms. Without showing the specific code for your individual failure case, this question is just a call for speculation.

Comment: (Possible duplicates, from which this question should be [edit]ed to distinguish: [Why is a tilde not expanded in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276909/why-is-a-tilde-in-a-path-not-expanded-in-a-shell-script); [Why isn't tilde (~) expanding in double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871596/why-isnt-tilde-expanding-inside-double-quotes))

Comment: Hey @CharlesDuffy, thanks for commenting! It looks like I blindly assumed `$HOME` would be defined, and it was not.  Once I manually defined it, everything worked as intended.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Something is very wrong if `HOME` is not defined. From section 8.3, Other Environment Variables, of the POSIX spec: "The system shall initialize [HOME] at the time of login to be a pathname of the user's home directory."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen several ways. To take a few:

- [Why is a tilde in a path not expanded in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276909/why-is-a-tilde-in-a-path-not-expanded-in-a-shell-script) - If a tilde is literal content in a variable, tilde expansion will not take at variable expansion time.
- [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash) - If a tilde expression is created via other expansions (ie. `~$user`), alternate means are required to expand it.
- If `$HOME` is not defined, tilde expansion will not take place.