# Duplicate a directory and keep file names but all contents are identical

Tags: bash

I have a directory "~/files" which contains files a through z with varying contents.
I have a file "test" whose contents are "text"

I want to create directory "~/new" containing files a through z with contents "text"

Example bash script:

```
for filename in "~/files"; do
    cp "~/test" "~/new/filename"
done
```

Comment: *I want to create directory "~/new" containing files a through z with contents "text"* `mkdir ~/new && for f in ~/new/{a..z}; do echo text > "$f"; done`

Comment: `~` won't be expanded when it's in quotes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871596/why-isnt-tilde-expanding-inside-double-quotes)) -- use e.g. `~/files`, `~/"files"`, or `"$HOME/files"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! @Shawn, I don't actually want them to be named a-z, they are placeholder names. The real file names reside in the original directory. Also, curious, why am I getting downvoted? Should I have placed my question somewhere else? I would like some guidance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the contents of the original file, don't copy it. Just use the filename as the name of a new file.

```
for f in ~/files/*
do
    echo text > ~/new/"${f##*/}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked it a little bit though; I don't want the file to literally contain "text," I should have clarified that it was a placeholder for some obscure contents that aren't actually text. It works for what I want when I change the echo line to:
`cp test ~/new/"${f##*/}"`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only real question you have is how to make the destination files have the same names as the source files, but in a different directory, and then you just want to repeat the same actions for all of them.